# Ошибка при получении токена Yoomoney в python

Tags: python

При попытке получить токен Yoomoney в python, выдает ошибку "yoomoney.exceptions.EmptyToken: Response token is empty. Repeated request for an authorization token". На иных сайтах ссылаются на неправильное заполнение redirect_uri, но в программе такая-же ссылка как и в Настройках приложения в Yoomoney.

Скриншот настроек в Yoomoney:
[image: Скриншот настроек в Yoomoney]
Код для получения токена:

````
from yoomoney import Authorize

Authorize(
      client_id="Тут находился токен",
      redirect_uri="https://t.me/my_perviy_bot_bot",
      scope=["account-info","operation-history","operation-details","incoming-transfers","payment-p2p","payment-shop",])```
````